# What is the next number in the sequence 3, 5, 11, 71, 13, 14, 95, 76, 38,?

Tags: number-sequence

Just another number sequence puzzle!

> 3, 5, 11, 71, 13, 14, 95, 76, 38,?

Can you solve this?

Comment: What could be the context of such sequence ? Adding little hints that helps to build the beginning of a search are really appreciated in order to avoid using directly polynomial equations.

Comment: @Anton Sorry, I cannot provide any hints since very first hint is so profound that it could lead you to the solution. Though you can always twist your mind a little bit more!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the next number should be :

> 901.

To compute this, we must open a list of primes, for example : https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt

This sequence is built from this list, by next rules:
1. You should take only the numbers, on position, which is prime.
2. You should reverse this number.

It works pretty well, but in the given sequence, I think you ommited the 3rd element $11$. Let's see:

> 2 - 3 
>  3 - 5 
>  5 - 11 - 11
>  7 - 17 - 71
>  11 - 31 - 13
>  13 - 41 - 14
>  17 - 59 - 95
>  19 - 67 - 76
>  23 - 83 - 38
>  29
>  - 109 - 901

The final sequence is

> 3, 5, 11, 71, 13, 14, 95, 76, 38, 901.

Comment: Yes. Higher order. But use spoilers.

Comment: @Strawberry, thank you for advice! It was my first answer and i didn`t know how to make good formating.

Comment: If correct, this solution really deserves double scoring due to incorrect input data.

Comment: Great job Igor.

Comment: @IgorDergunov Finally, someone cracked it!

Answer (score 0):

I think

> 39

Explanation

> 3 + 5 + 71 + 13 + 14 + 95 + 76 + 38 = 315, This sequence has 8 number, 315 / 8 = 39.

Comment: Not the correct answer!

Comment: Sorry :( Can you delete my answer? (I can't now)

Comment: even I cannot delete your answer.

Comment: Oh ok. Who can do it?

Comment: @404 you can delete your own answer, on the bottom left of it you should have a "delete" link. But just because it's wrong doesn't mean you have to delete it.